# Rstan: How to read in multiple vectors from R to Stan

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, vector, rstan

Say I have some vectors in Stan

```
vector[100] mu[20]
```

This means `mu` is 20 vectors each of length 100.

Do I read this in as `mu = martix(NA,nrow=100,ncol=20)` or as `mu = array(NA,dim=c(100,20))` from R?
(I hope I'm not getting the dimensions mixed up)

Or is incorrect and do you this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two options to provide the `matrix`/`array` or a `list` of vectors. In your example you have to change the order for rows and columns.

The `rstan` error messages are clear so you will know if something goes wrong with dimensions.

```r
library(rstan)
# dummy parameters
scode <- "
data {
  vector[100] mu[20];
}
parameters {
  real y[2]; 
}
"
# Both fit pass without errors
fit1 <- stan(
  model_code = scode,
  data = list(mu = matrix(rnorm(20 * 100), nrow = 20, ncol = 100))
) 
fit2 <- stan(
  model_code = scode, 
  data = list(mu = lapply(1:20, function(x) rnorm(100)))
)
```